# How to detect if a Chrome tab is playing audio?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'd like to execute a console command on a specific tab and receive a boolean answer whether the tab is playing audio.
(Usually stated as a little speaker icon near the tab's title)

Can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can detect if a Chrome tab is playing audio with a Chrome Extension, using the [chrome.tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs). The API provides a boolean `audible` property, as described below:

> Whether the tab has produced sound over the past couple of seconds
>   (but it might not be heard if also muted). Equivalent to whether the
>   speaker audio indicator is showing.

**Source:** https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs

There's no way to access the tabs from the console itself, as it is run from the context of the current page. In the background page of a Chrome Extension, you have access to all the tabs, and you can query them using the API outlined above. Your extension can simply provide a panel that displays a list of all the open tabs and a flag to say whether the audio is playing.

**Aside:** If you just want to quickly mute HTML5 Audio/Video in the current tab using the Chrome console, you can run the following (the `$$` is equivalent to `document.querySelectorAll()`):

```
$$('video', 'audio').forEach((element) => element.muted = true);
```

Comment: Thanks mate!
My intention is to find out whether the tab is playing music to a small analytics app, that detects console errors and the client wants to know whether audio has been loaded to a given url.
I'll try using the chrome.tabs API.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps something like this will solve your problem:
`!!Array.prototype.find.call(document.querySelectorAll('audio,video'),function(elem){return elem.duration > 0 && !elem.paused})`

Detects both audio and video elements currently playing. Works cross browsers.

Comment: Can't detect because Audio is playing from javascript Audio object